# Why is Visual Studio constantly trying to create a 'dummy/empty' file?

Tags: visual-studio, process-monitor

I just ran [Process Monitor (by Sys Internals)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for the first time on this Win7 RTM machine to figure out the paths VS2008 uses when compiling (so i can exclude them from my AV).

Check this out ....

[alt text http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/517/wtfdevenv.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/517/wtfdevenv.png)

WTF? Every 6 seconds (or so), it's trying to CreateFile at some invalid path. 
If u notice (in the pic) i've turned off all details EXCEPT the file system activity.

Anyone have any idea's what is going on?

EDIT: Took another screenie with clearer info.
EDIT 2: Can anyone else replicate this? If so, please add a comment if u can.
EDIT 3: Could it be because of a plugin i have? eg. Resharper?

Comment: +1 You just asked a Visual Studio question I don't immediately know the answer to. :o

Answer (score 2):

It is not trying to create a file, if you look at the detail column it is doing "read data/list directory". Probably, it is doing some kind of `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` loop, in order to resolve header file includes.

Comment: I don't have Windows 7 or VS 2008, so probably not

Comment: I can replicate this with VS2010 on Win7 64 Enterprise.I don't have Resharper installed, so it won't be it.

Answer (score 1):

The [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) function is not just for creating files, but also for opening existing files and directories for reading.

Comment: So then it's trying to open an *empty* file or directory?